# Adding the Propionyl-CoA Pathway to E.coli

Tags: homework, biotechnology

So I'm trying to simulate the production of 3-Hydroxypropionic Acid with E.coli via the Propionyl-CoA Pathway.
However I'm not really sure how the production in the pathway goes.
I got the following picture:
[image]

If I understand it correctly the pathway goes:
Acetyl-Coa--> Propionate --> Propionyl-CoA --> .... --> 3-HP
When adding these reactions in Cobra are the stoichiometric coefficients always just 1?

---

Source of the figure:
[Luo H, Zhou D, Liu X, Nie Z, Quiroga- Sánchez DL, Chang Y (2016) Production of 3- Hydroxypropionic Acid via the Propionyl-CoA Pathway Using Recombinant *Escherichia coli* Strains. PLoS ONE 11(5): e0156286. doi:10.1371/journal. pone.0156286](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0156286)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I understand it correctly the pathway goes: Acetyl-CoA --> Propionate --> Proprionyl-CoA --> ... --> 3-HP

Not exactly. The first reaction is:
$propionate + acetyl\textrm-CoA \rightarrow propionyl\textrm-CoA + acetate$
The CoA group is transferred from acetate to propionate. The following reactions are an oxidation to acryloyl-CoA and a subsequent hydration to 3-HP-CoA. Lastly the CoA group is transferred back to acetate.

Propionate is a 3 carbon molecule and so is 3-HP. So stoechiometric coefficients of 1 seem logical.